# What happened to Android Filterscript in 4.3?

Tags: android, performance, parallel-processing, gpgpu, renderscript

There used to be a subset of Android Renderscript called Filterscript. It was supposed to execute faster than Renderscript on some devices due to reduced complexity. Here is a [thread about Filterscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917106/where-is-the-filterscript-documentation-and-how-can-i-use-it) on SO.

Although Filterscript was officially announced just [one version ago](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html) (4.2) I can't find Filterscript mentioned in the current (4.3) Android Renderscript [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html) any more.

So the question is: What happened to Filterscript? Does the distinction between RS and FS still make sense? Has it been deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

FilterScript most certainly still exists. We did make a lot of doc updates for 4.3, so perhaps those sections disappeared (or got folded into more general sections). In general, you can still use the .fs suffix to denote FilterScript kernels. These should be more easily accelerated than .rs files due to the forced use of "__attribute__((kernel))". If you use this attribute to declare your kernels, your .rs files should also be easier to run on the GPU.